# CKEDITOR using applyStyle removes <br />

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to:

- select some text,
- then press a button
- and after that surround the selected text with a `span`-tag

Example:

- [ - start of selection
- ] - end of selection

`This is the begi[ning of my text and he]re is the end`

should transformed to:

`This is the begi<span class="mySpanClass">ning of my text and he</span>re is the end`

To reach my goal, i've added a ckeditor plugin with a dialog...
This is the code (for what happened, when you press the 'ok' button of the dialog)

```
  onOk: function () {
    editor.fire('saveSnapshot');

    let colorClass = createColorClass.call(this);
    //  removeColorClasses(editor);
    editor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({attributes: {'class': colorClass}}));

    editor.fire("saveSnapshot");
  }
```

So, I'm using internal ckeditor stuff to add the span class (this line)

`editor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({attributes: {'class': colorClass}}));`

Now the **problem** i have:

Adding the span class removes all empty lines (`<br />`) means:

```
M[y 1. Line

My 2. li]ne
```

which is in the ckEditor something like:

```
M[y 1. line
<br />
My 2. li]ne
```

is converted to:

```
M<span class="MySpanClass>y 1. line
My 2. li</span>ne
```

What can i do, to keep the `<br />'s`?
(They only get removed when i'm using my plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simplest way is to use `new CKEDITOR.style(...)` the right way (to create a span-Element)!

```
let spanTag = new CKEDITOR.style({element: 'span', attributes: {'class': colorClass}});
editor.applyStyle(spanTag);
```